# How to read key=value pair file from remote host into variables in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, key-value

I have this file in my remote host:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale  
LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

How can I read that and import hose key=value pairs into variables to use in the following tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the file and put it, for example, into the *`inventory_dir`*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_fetch_file: "{{ inventory_dir ~
                           '/' ~
                           inventory_hostname ~
                           '-locale' }}"
    - fetch:
        flat: true
        src: /etc/default/locale
        dest: "{{ my_fetch_file }}"
```

Use [ini](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/ini.html#ini-read-data-from-a-ini-file) loookup plugin to read the values

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_LANG: "{{ lookup('ini',
                            'LANG type=properties file=' ~
                            my_fetch_file) }}"
```

It is possible to read a list of variables into a dictionary. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_vars: "{{ my_vars|default({})|
                     combine({item:
                              lookup('ini',
                                      item ~ 
                                      ' type=properties file=' ~
                                      my_fetch_file)}) }}"
      loop: [LANG, LANGUAGE]
```

Then the debug below should print the values

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_vars[item]
      loop: [LANG, LANGUAGE]
```

---

> Q:  can you please clarify all those ~?

A: Quoting from [Math](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#math)

> **+** Adds two objects together. Usually the objects are numbers, but if both are strings or lists, you can concatenate them this way. This, however, is not the preferred way to concatenate strings! For string concatenation, have a look-see at the ~ operator. {{ 1 + 1 }} is 2.

Quoting from [Other Operators](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#other-operators)

> **~** Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them.
> {{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }} would return (assuming name is set to 'John') Hello John!.

Comment: I'm knew to ansible, can you please clarify all those `~`?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and I tried to use the above answers but I did not manage to get it working.
I finally found a simpler way to do it:

```
  - set_fact:
      "{{ item.split('=')[0] }}": "{{ item.split('=')[1] }}"
    when: "'=' in item"
    loop: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/default/locale').splitlines() }}"

  - name: Use variable
    debug:
      msg: "LANG:{{LANG}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use setup module and fact.d for gathering custom facts from remote host:

```
- name: "Create custom fact directory"
  file:
    path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d"
    state: "directory"

- name: "coping the custom fact file"
  copy:
    remote_src: yes
    src: /etc/default/locale
    dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/locale.fact
    mode: '755'

- name: "gathering custom facts"
  setup:
    filter: ansible_local

- debug:
    var: ansible_local.locale

- name: "remove the custom fact directory"
  file:
    path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d"
    state: absent
```